# Table tag inside label tag with display:block?

Tags: javascript, html

I know you shouldn't have `<table>`-tags inside `<label>`-tags because `<table>` is flow content. However, I'm trying to connect a table to a radio button and for that I'm using the `for`-attribute for label but I can't put my `<table>` inside a `<label>` without getting error.

My questions are: Is it OK to put a table inside a label if the label uses `display: block` or it the only way to fix this is by using JavaScript and removing the `<label>`-tag all together?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fgjtsp45/1/

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="1">
<label for="1" class="my-label">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td> 
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td> 
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</label>

<input type="radio" name="gender" id="2">
<label for="2" class="my-label">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td> 
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td> 
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</label>
```

Comment: What is the point of having a `table` in your `label`? `table` should only be used to display a table.

Comment: Yeah, I ask the same thing. WHY are you putting the `<table>` there? For what purpose? The example provides absolutely no reason for having a table.

Comment: I could see it the other way around, using the table to display/align the radio button and label. But, as the others have said, there is no reason to put a table inside of a label. You'll accomplish the same thing by simply putting the content "My content card" as the label body. If there is specific formatting/blocking you want to do, that can be done using CSS

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie The end goal is that I'll have many tables, each linked to a radio button. I want the radio buttons to be selectable by clicking on their respective table. See updated JSFiddle and code.